# Executing WordPress Shortcodes in a String

Tags: php, wordpress, eval, shortcode

I have a string that may contain shortcodes such as "this is a string with [anyshortcode1] and this is [anyshortcode2]".  I want to display the string with the shortcodes running where they are placed.  When I echo this string out, it doesn't do the shortcodes, it just prints them out leaving them in brackets.  I tried to fix this by using code like the following:

```
$string_with_shortcodes = "this is a string with [anyshortcode1] and this is [anyshortcode2]";
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
preg_match_all("/$pattern/",$string_with_shortcodes, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $short) {
    $string_with_shortcodes = str_replace($short, 'do_shortcode("' . $short . '")', $string_with_shortcodes);
}
eval("\$string_with_shortcodes = \"$string_with_shortcodes\";");
echo $string_with_shortcodes;
```

This successfully does the string replacement, but causes an error with the eval function:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Am I using the eval function wrong?  Or is there a simpler way to accomplish running shortcodes from a string?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to execute the `shortcode` from within the string you have to use the `do_shortcode()` function.

This is how to use it:

```
$string_with_shortcodes = "this is a string with [anyshortcode1] and this is [anyshortcode2]";
echo do_shortcode($string_with_shortcodes);
```

If this does not work, then something wrong with your installation.

Also note, that `eval()` is not the best command in your code .. ! :)

Finally make sure that the shortcode still exists. There are many many themes that using shortcodes for styling the content, and then, when the user installs another theme, the previous shortcodes are not functional anymore, because they will be removed with the previous theme.

Comment: Wow thank you! I was making that way too complicated. I was misunderstanding how do_shortcode worked.

Comment: If you found your answer, please mark it as the answer. This way you save time from other StackOverflow usres ;) Ah... And Welcome to WordPress World !! :)

Comment: Further, if you have something like `$str = '<div>[shortcode]</div>'` it also works if you do `echo do_shortcode($str)` like charm

Answer (score 2):

```
$string_with_shortcodes = str_replace($short, do_shortcode($short), $string_with_shortcodes);
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do with Eval.

Comment: He's trying to let his site get hacked by anyone who can write a shortcode with `eval` is what he's doing.

Comment: Whether or not he knows that's what he's doing is another question.